# Passing a function using op_kwargs (PythonVirtualOperator) in Airflow Dag

Tags: python, airflow

I have a dag with two functions and I want to call one function in another in the dag. I tried two approaches:

Approach 1:

```
def upload_to_AWS(df):
    #code to upload to AWS

def A1(callback):
    df = obj.fucntion1()
    callback(df)


with DAG(f"d1", default_args=args) as dag:
    prod_op = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id="A1",
    python_callable=A1,
    requirements=["NAME OF LIBRARY"],
    system_site_packages=False,
    op_kwargs={'callback': upload_to_AWS}
)
```

Error: Issue with pickling; arg_dict = pickle.load(f)\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Approach 2:

```
def upload_to_AWS(df):
    #code to upload to AWS

def A1(callback):
    df = obj.fucntion1()
    upload_to_AWS(df)


with DAG(f"d1", default_args=args) as dag:
    prod_op = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id="A1",
    python_callable=A1,
    requirements=["NAME OF LIBRARY"],
    system_site_packages=False
)
```

Error: No module named upload_to_AWS

Any suggestions?

Comment: `["NAME OF LIBRARY"]` does not look like a correct specification of required packages. I would remove the `requirements` parameter completely and try again.

Comment: Does not work without it as well.